# Separate column with comma

Tags: php, mysql

i can separate join column with comma, but how to remove comma if on the second column is null?
in below, i have 2 column i want join otot2 and otot3
1. how to not shown comma after otot2 if otot3 null?
2. and how to not shown anything comma if otot2 and otot 3 null?
3. otot2 and otot3 flexible ( not always has data)

here my php code for output query:

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($hasil) > 0)
{   
    $response = array();
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil))
    {
        $h['main muscle'] = $data['otot1'];
        $h['other muscle'] = $data['otot2'].', '.$data['otot3'];

        array_push($response, $h);
    }
    $response["success"];
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: if(isnull($data['otot3']))else ..

Comment: @Dagon can you give a full code?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be -

```
$response = array();
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil))
{
    // other code

    $temp = array($data['otot2'], $data['otot3']); // Store them in array
    $temp = array_filter($temp); // remove empty values
    $h['other muscle'] = implode(',', $temp); // implode them with (,)

    // Other codes

    array_push($response, $h);
}
```

By using `array_filter` & `implode` you don't have to worry about the `,`, as `array_filter` would remove the empty values and if there is **2** values in the array them the string would be `,` separated else not.

Or you can try this also

```
$h['other muscle'] = $data['otot2'];
if($data['otot3'] !== null)
    $h['other muscle'] .= ', ' . $data['otot3']; // Concatenate
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/560288)

Comment: Thanks for help, im try and if otot3 null, otot2 stil shown up with comma

Comment: Yes im try your code, but comma still shown after otot2 when otot3 null , and same like otot2 and otot3 null comma still show

Comment: @F_X It should not. Check the demo. What code you have implemented.

Comment: all your code you give im implement in my php code, but comma still show